# android 4.1.2 transparent pixels appear black

Tags: android, xml, drawable, transparent

follow is my drawable xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape android:shape="oval" xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<gradient
    android:centerColor="@color/black"
    android:endColor="@android:color/transparent"
    android:gradientRadius="30dp"
    android:startColor="@android:color/black"
    android:type="radial" />
```

end color is transparent, it's work on 5.x 6.x,
but it's display all the black on the 4.1.2,

and i found the same problem when i tried used transparent png,
also work on 5.x, 6.x,
display black on 4.1.2

is transparent not supported on < 5.0?, how can i do, thank you